# Ubuntu update removed Spotiy, Google Chrome, Dropbox and Mullvad

Tags: google-chrome, dropbox

Yesterday I dowloaded an update to 12.04 LT and today I discovered it removed Spotify, Google Chrome, Dropbox and Mullvad.

Any easy way to get them back?  I don`t want to spend more time on reinstalling, cause I mean I have spent enough time on Ubuntu.

If Ubuntu want to be userfriend this should not be possible to happen.

Comment: I have two questions. 
First: what is your prior version? 
And second: Did you try to launch them from terminal? Did you install them manually or from ubuntu software center? Errr... actually were three questions

Answer (score 0):

During a system upgrade, third party software sources are disabled to prevent conflicts with the core OS installation. You will have to re-enable the sources to download the software again. This can be done from "[software sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)"

Some applications can be reinstalled through the Ubuntu Software Center, but I believe the ones you listed are all third party apps. So you'll have to either re-enable the sources and install from there, or re-install them from the developers websites.